# How to format a column with this format: 000.000 in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, format

I have a column that I imported as text. It has numbers like 511.182, 367.340, 342.001, etc.

I tried doing:

```
UPDATE databasename 
SET accountcode = format(accountcode,"000.000")
WHERE len([accountcode])>0;
```

However, this just caused every row to have the last three digits after the period to be 000. In the example I gave, it would now show as: 511.000, 367.000, and 342.000

Comment: Try to convert the field to numeric , then format it. Like format(val(accountCode),”000.000”)

Comment: That seemed to have worked, thank you sir!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the solution.

Had to make it a text field, and then did the following code:

```
UPDATE databasename
SET accountcode = format(val(accountCode),"000.000")
WHERE len([accountcode])>0;
```

Worked perfectly.